# Clojure custom Java Interop

Tags: java, clojure, interop

I'm trying to find the best documentation and information on integrating custom Java files into a Clojure project. I've reviewed the project [Enlight](https://github.com/mikera/enlight) and see that the files are all `.java` files under the `/src/main/java` directory. Unfortunately it doesn't use Leiningen (what I'm using) so I can't see how it is called together the java files.

Suppose I want to use a big Java project from Clojure, like [MALLET](https://github.com/mimno/Mallet), which is abstracted into oblivion that a standard, major, main entry point like `public static void main ()` cannot be found. Do I just dump every `.java` file into my classpath and hope for the best?

Comment: Having java files in the classpath is of no use to clojure at all. You can require a java lib from leiningen in the same way you would a clojure lib, and the classes will become available for interop in the same way you would use any of the built in classes in the jvm. If you are asking how to do interop, I think that's covered by other questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include your own `.java` files in Leiningen project:

```
(defproject my-project "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  ; ...
  :java-source-paths ["src/main/java" "src_other/java"]) ; It's up to you how to structure paths
```

In this setup your `.java` files compilation will be managed by Leiningen.

To include existing Java project which is available in some of Maven repositories, just add dependency. For MALLET it will look like:

```
(defproject my-project "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  ; ...
  :dependencies [[cc.mallet/mallet "2.0.7"]])
```

Finally, if the goal is to include private `jar` file - the best option is to create local Maven repository.

In all of these cases you will be able to do normal Java <-> Clojure interop.